# Searching for a Regular Expression which follows "(/(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/?)*)" AND does not start with "/xyz"

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine

I m currently working on a python-project with [webapp2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/running) where you map a URL (defined by a regular expression) to a specific handler-class. (This class handles the URL-request and responds to it)

Currently all requests following the regular expression :

```
(/(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/?)*)
```

are mapped to my HomeHandler() class.

Now i need to change the regex to follow:

```
URL DOES NOT START with "/xyz"  AND followed by "(/(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/?)*)"
```

Example:

```
/xyz/abcdefABCD2341/488888/edit -> should NOT be matched
/notxyz/abcdefABCD2341/488888/edit -> should be matched
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: if you dont want anything in the string, you can use _^_ before it.Like [^/xyz]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should solve your problem... I've inserted negative lookahead that checks for xyz and added `^` and `$` so it checks the entire string matches, otherwise your regex is unchanged

```
^(/(?!xyz)(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/?)*)$
```

[Your test case](https://www.debuggex.com/r/zi11iMSGsC9CWrV1), change the start to xyz or not

Answer (score 3):

The other answer regex's are correct, but for Google App Engine, the app.yaml is order dependent, so you can add handlers to cover your /xyz case, then a handler for everything else.

So for your siutation:

```
# app.yaml
handlers:

- url: /xyz.*
  script: xyzHandler.app

- url: .*
  script: homeHandler.app
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the "negative lookahead assertion" can help you. Go to the link below and search for "negative lookahead assertion". 
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html
In your case, you may try:

```
^(?!/xyz)(/(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/?)*)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should probably be just:

```
^/(?!xyz)[\w/-]+$
```